# Error when creating simple command with Select from discord ui discord py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am currently tring to do a command where the user can choose in which channels my bot can write into, but I get the error `discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body In components.0.components.0.options: Must be 6 or more in length.`  when trying to run the command.

At first, I thought it was related to the channel names but even after making them longer than 6 characters it still didn't work, and I don't have any other ideas of why it does this error. Could I have some help please ?
Here is my code :

```
@bot.command()
async def setup(ctx):
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
        await ctx.send("Select the channels where the bot must write :")
        write_select_options = []
        for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
            if isinstance(channel, discord.TextChannel) and channel.permissions_for(ctx.guild.me).send_messages:
                write_select_options.append(discord.SelectOption(label=channel.name, value=str(channel.id)))

        write_select = Select(
            placeholder="Select channels",
            options=write_select_options,
            min_values=1,
            max_values=len(ctx.guild.channels)
        )
        write_view = View()
        write_view.add_item(write_select)
        await ctx.send(view=write_view)

        def write_check(interaction):
            return interaction.user == ctx.author

        write_interaction = await bot.wait_for("select_option", check=write_check)
```

Here is the entire error (I just changed paths) :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 235, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/main.py", line 166, in setup
    await ctx.send(view=write_view)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/context.py", line 1024, in send
    return await super().send(
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 1561, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, params=params)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 745, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In components.0.components.0.options: Must be 6 or more in length.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 1350, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1029, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 244, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In components.0.components.0.options: Must be 6 or more in length.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is probably happening because you are defining `max_values` with a value greater than the total number of options. Try replacing:

```py
max_values=len(ctx.guild.channels)
```

with

```py
max_values=len(write_select_options)
```